# get rid of count function in power bi

Tags: count, powerbi, linechart

The line chart is showing count to instead of the true values . I still have a problem even though I Selected "Don't summarize" in Summarization, I checked data types, all is alright, But I still have this count to function. Please any suggestion ?

The line chart is showing count to instead of the true values . I still have a problem even though I Selected "Don't summarize" in Summarization, I checked data types, all is alright, But I still have this count to function. Please any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change aggregation from *Count* to *Sum* you clearly have data type *text*, not *number*. Everyone will see that as soon as you post your sample data.